# Chartjs highlights multiple points in row

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js

I'm using Chartjs, and its not highlighting properly.  Its only supposed to highlight one data point at a time, but for some reason it highlights all data points to the right of my mouse.  I've attached a gif to demonstrate:

[image]

My data structure is as follows:

```
{
    "labels": ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    "datasets": [{
        "data": [null, null, "5.00", null, null, null, "5.00", null, "2.00", null, "7.00", null, null, null],
        "label": "item 1",
        "fillColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
        "strokeColor": "rgb(255, 153, 0)",
        "pointColor": "rgba(198,229,217",
        "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
        "pointHighlightFill": "#fff",
        "pointHighlightStroke": "rgba(220,220,220,1)"
    }, {
        "data": [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "7.00", null, null, null],
        "label": "Item 2",
        "fillColor": "rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.46)",
        "strokeColor": "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
        "pointColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
        "pointHighlightFill": "#fff",
        "pointHighlightStroke": "rgba(220,220,220,1)"
    }, {
        "data": [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
        "label": "Item 3",
        "fillColor": "rgba(198,229,217,.2)",
        "strokeColor": "rgba(198,229,217,1)",
        "pointColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
        "pointHighlightFill": "#fff",
        "pointHighlightStroke": "rgba(220,220,220,1)"
    }]
}
```

If you can see whats going wrong that would be great.  Its a pretty complex app I'm building, so I may be making a mistake elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Chart.defaults.Line.pointHitDetectionRadius` option? The smaller it is the more accurate the tooltips will be

Comment: I checked that.  Anyways, I gave up and switched to amCharts.  Amcharts now has a free version.  Its not FOSS, but I'm not making a FOSS project